# CUnit : undefined reference to `CU_assertImplementation'

Tags: c, cunit

### compiled it using : **cc -o test testtest.c -lcunit** , but still cant run the tests properly. they crash for some reason :)

I'm working on a project and i have recently convinced myself that i should continue in an testdriven approach. Mainly because the project itself is growing and i want proof of that all functions work.

But i bump into some problems while doing a cunit tutorial.
http://cunit.sourceforge.net/doc/writing_tests.html

This is my cunit test file :

```
#include <CUnit/CUnit.h>

main(){
    test_maxi();
}

int maxi(int i1, int i2){
      return (i1 > i2) ? i1 : i2;
}

void test_maxi(void){
  CU_ASSERT(maxi(0,2) == 2);
  CU_ASSERT(maxi(0,-2) == 0);
  CU_ASSERT(maxi(2,2) == 2);
 }
```

i get these errors when i try to compile it :

> testtest.c:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to
>   `CU_assertImplementation' testtest.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference
>   to`CU_assertImplementation' testtest.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined
>   reference to `CU_assertImplementation' collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

I used google and i think it got something todo with linking? But i didnt get much help out of it.

Best Regards
Rickard

Comment: I think you did not install `cuint` correctly. What method did you use to install?

Comment: I solved it. gcc -Wall -o test basicexample.c -lcunit

Comment: @macbug please transform that comment to an answer

Comment: This was years ago, cant remember.

Comment: I transformed that comment for you. Please do not add _solved_ in a title.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

compiled it using:

```
gcc -Wall -o test basicexample.c -lcunit
```